# Need system wide equalizer on raspbian+kodi. Not sure how to do this.

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I have a great surround set, but it does not have an EQ built in (I can modify bass/treble, but it is very bass heavy and I want more control).

I don't really get why Kodi has no EQ built in, but I understand it has been stripped due to stability issues?

I have tried setting up ALSAEQUAL, but I've read that it's not supported and that Kodi bypasses this framework somehow.I'm quite new to linux so I'm not completely familiar with ALSA, and what it does.

Is there anything I can try to get an EQ in Kodi, or system wide? Without the EQ Kodi is basically useless for me due to an unbalanced sound.